# Как считать value из элемента span? Никак не выходит

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

В общем у меня не получается считать value из span. В любом случае пишет undefined.
Вот пример:

```js
var number = document.getElementById('number').value;
console.log(typeof number);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <span id="number">10</span>
</body>  
</html>
```

Подскажите что я делаю не так.

Comment: `var number = document.getElementById('number').textContent;` или `var num = number.textContent;`

Comment: А можно добавить в самом теге value = " ", и как в этом случае считать?

Comment: я не понял вопрос

Comment: ну вот к примеру есть span, и я вот так напишу: < span value="10" >< /span >
ну то есть теперь value отдельно
можно ли так считать его?

Comment: `.getAttribute('value')`

Comment: огромное спасибо